# How do I load automatically when uploading a file to html input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

when i put a file in html input i want to upload via ajax post.(without clicks) It works after I click the boot button in my current code.
My code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#but_upload").click(function () {
    $('#img-loag-scrin').html('');
    $('div#img-loag-scrin').css('display', 'block').prepend('<img id="img_akb" src="https://' + HTTP + '/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="buff-load" style="display:block;margin:10px auto; cursor: wait;">');
    var fd = new FormData();
    var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
    fd.append('file', files);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://localhost.uz/ajax/ajax_img.php?act=upload',
      dataType: "json",
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (response) {
        if (response != 0) {
          $('#img-loag-scrin').prepend(response.scrins);
          $('#textrea').val($('#textrea').val() + " " + response.textrea);
          $('#img_akb').remove();
        } else {
          alert('File not uploaded');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
  <input type="button" class="sf_button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
</form>
```

When html is inserted into the input file, without clicking on the button, the file should be loaded. After the image is loaded, the image must disappear from the input

Comment: Are you telling about `onchange` event? `$("#file").change(function () {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#file').unbind().on('change', function () {
    $('#img-loag-scrin').html('');
    $('div#img-loag-scrin').css('display', 'block').prepend('<img id="img_akb" src="https://' + HTTP + '/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="buff-load" style="display:block;margin:10px auto; cursor: wait;">');
    var fd = new FormData();
    var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
    fd.append('file', files);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://localhost/ajax/ajax_img.php?act=upload',
      dataType: "json",
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (response) {
        if (response != 0) {
          $('#img-loag-scrin').prepend(response.scrins);
          $('#textrea').val($('#textrea').val() + " " + response.textrea);
          $('#img_akb').remove();
        } else {
          alert('File not uploaded');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

html code

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
</form>
```